# Symfony5; cant access joined entity values

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony5

in my add hours controller i can see and access the variables in the collection
but when i try to access them in the maincontroller, i only get an empty collection, see maincontroller

[image: dd($projects[0]->getProjectHours());]

My ProjectHours entity

```php
/**
 * Class ProjectHours
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ProjectHours
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $timestamp_start;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $timestamp_end;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Project", inversedBy="project_hours")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="project_id", nullable=false, referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $project;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="dateinterval")
     */
    private $duration;


    public function addProjectHours(ProjectHours $ph)
    {
        $this->project_hours[] = $ph;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|ProjectHours[]
     */
    public function getProjectHours()
    {
        return $this->project_hours;
    }
```

My Project entity

```php
/**
 * Class Project
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Project
{


    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $name;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="projects")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable=false, referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\ProjectHours", mappedBy="project", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $project_hours;



    public function addProjectHours(ProjectHours $ph)
    {
        $this->project_hours[] = $ph;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|ProjectHours[]
     */
    public function getProjectHours()
    {
        return $this->project_hours;
    }
```

My addHours controller

```php
  #[Route('projects/{project}/new', name: 'app_newHours')]
    public function index(Request $request, $project): Response
    {

        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $project = str_replace('%20', ' ', $project);

        $hour_entry = new ProjectHours();

        $hour_entry->setTimestampStart(new \DateTime('NOW'));
        $hour_entry->setTimestampEnd(new \DateTime('NOW'));

        $pj = $em->getRepository(Project::class)->findOneBy(array('name'=> $project));
        $hour_entry->setProject($pj);

        $form = $this->createForm(AddHoursClassType::class, $hour_entry );
        $form->handleRequest($request);


        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
        {
            $start = $hour_entry->getTimestampStart();
            $end = $hour_entry->getTimestampEnd();

            if($end > $start)
            {
                $interval = $start->diff($end);

                $hour_entry->setDuration($interval);

                $pj->addProjectHours($hour_entry);


                //store to database
                $em->persist($hour_entry);
                $em->persist($pj);
                $em->flush();
                $this->addFlash('success', 'Hours added successfully!');
            }
            else
            {
                $this->addFlash('error', 'End time must be later than start time!');
            }
        }
```

and finally in my Maincontroller

```php
 /**
         * @Route("/projects", name="app_mainscreen")
         */
        public function Main()
        {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $user = $this->getUser();
            $projects = $em->getRepository(Project::class)->findBy(array('user' => $user));
            $hourlist = $this->getHourList($projects, $em);

            dd($projects[0]->getProjectHours());


            return $this->render('home.html.twig', [
                'projectlist' => $projects,
                'hourlist' => $hourlist
            ]);
        }
```

If anyone can help me it would be highly appreciated!

Comment: try `dd($projects[0]->getProjectHours()->toArray());`

Comment: @ArleighHix Thanks a lot! this was exactly what i needed!

Comment: I've added an answer for this one and up-voted, as this gets asked a lot and usually resolved with comments then removed. There are some with answers, but they all point to changing the lazy loading for the collection which causes a hit on performance, when most askers usually just want to dump in dev. I would have marked as duplicate but there is no good duplicate that I have been able to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the collection just holds a reference to the entities until you access them (lazy loading), indicated by `#initialized: false`. Since you are dumping before accessing any contents of the collection, it appears to be empty. This behavior is designed to improve performance in cases where you may not want to accesss the collection, then the related entities do not need to be fetched.
For debugging purposes, you can force all the items in the collection to load by converting the collection to an array with it's built-in method `toArray`:

```
dd($projects[0]->getProjectHours()->toArray());
```

Normally, the individual items should load as you iterate through the collection in your template (`toArray` is not necessary).

```
{% for project in projectlist %}
  Project {{ project.name }} hours:
  <ul>
  {% for hour in project.projectHours %}
    <li>
      Started: {{ hour.timestampStart|date('g:ia D, M jS, Y') }}<br>
      Ended: {{ hour.timestampEnd|date('g:ia D, M jS, Y') }}    
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I needed to manipulate some of the data in the controller after retrieving, but thanks a lot anyhow!!